# Цикл по множеству dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, for

Есть много датафреймов и есть список с их названиями : `tables = ['dfa', 'dfb', 'dfc', 'dfd', 'dfe']` Во всех таблицах есть столбец с названием 'Sum'. Нужно ко всем применить одинаковое выражение, например: `df.Sum.astype('float64')`. Но  в цикле for переменная-итератор воспринимается как строка а не имя датафрейма и выдаёт ошибку: `for i in tables: i.Sum.astype('float64')`
Как сделать чтобы переменная читалась как имя датафрейма? Пробовал обернуть в eval или exec - не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите апострофы:

```
tables = [dfa, dfb, dfc, dfd, dfe]
```

Другой подход:

```
tables = ['dfa', 'dfb', 'dfc', 'dfd', 'dfe']

for i in tables:
    locals()[i].Sum.astype('float64')
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Стандартная функция `locals()` возвращает словарь всех местных переменных, причем ключами являются их имена в виде строк и значениями самые объекты.

Comment: Так он пишет ошибку при создании списка что нет переменных с таким именем

Comment: @Василий, когда у вас нет таких таблиц, как вы хотите работать с ними в цикле? Сначала должны быть таблицы, затем их список.

Comment: Точно! После создания таблиц можно создать список без кавычек! А есть какая-то функция чтобы преобразовать текстовые значения списка в имена датафрейма в ходе цикла for?

Comment: @Василий, я дополнил мой ответ — надеюсь, что вам мой *другой подход* будет полезным.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, но Sum это я имел ввиду название столбца - 'Sum') Значениям столбца Sum во всех массивах присвоить тип данных float64 ( аналогичная задача есть и для столбцов с датами).

Comment: @Василий, я понял и удалил это из моего ответа. Когда был мой отвес для вас полезным, вы можете принять его (клик на галочку влево от начала ответа). См. тоже [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Да спасибо! Поставил галку. Могли бы Вы также проконсультировать ещё по 1 моему вопросу? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478628/pandas-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85