# Pandas свод по всем столбцам кроме указанных

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Как в `pandas` сделать группировку по столбцам, но чтобы указать не те столбцы по которым свод, а те которые надо исключить? Например есть 20 столбцов, нужно сделать свод по 18 из них. Как правильно написать `groupby` или `pivot_table` чтобы указать только 2 "Ненужных" столбца, а не писать 18 нужных?

Comment: А если указать имена всех столбцов и через isin исключить ненужные? Не пробовали?

Comment: Это как? Напишите пож-та в виде кода.

Comment: @ВасилийСеми-Булатов полагаю, @Alexandr писал о такой операции `cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['colX','colY'])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда `df` - ваш датафрейм и `"Exclude1"`, `"Exclude2"` не нужные столбцы, вы можете сделать список остальных как

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ("Exclude1", "Exclude2")]
```

и применить этот список, например

```
df.goupby(cols).sum()
```

---

*Объяснение:*

- `df.cols` - хотя это объект типа `Index`, его возможно использовать как список всех имен столбцов
- `[col for col in df.columns if col not in ("Exclude1", "Exclude2")]` - это генератор списка. Я напишу его с излишними пробелами, чтобы лучше было видно его 3 части:

  ```
  [col     for col in df.columns     if col not in ("Exclude1", "Exclude2")]
  ```

  Перевод:

  - Список всех объектов `col`,
  - из списка (`for col in`) `df.columns`,
  - которые не находятся (`if col not in`) в кортеже `("Exclude1", "Exclude2")`.